# One-sample KS test's D-statistic peculiarity in R

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

First of all, let me explain what I'm after. I have a bunch of archaeological sites (point data) in GIS and a DEM-derived slope map. I classified the slope map into 1-degree interval classes and got the values for the sites. Now I wanted to test whether the values of the sites are significantly different than would be their random placement on the slope map, meaning that the slope of the terrain was an important factor when choosing a place for settlement. This seemed to be a good case for 1-sample KS test as the data is continuous and the reference distribution is actually known (the slope map itself). Also, the distributions are clearly non-normal.

So, I used `R`'s `ks.test` function so that the numeric vector x contained the classified values for the sites and y was set the cumulative distribution of the background distribution values via `ecdf` function: the classification into 1-degree bands was, of course, the same. However, the result is this:

```
One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  slope_sites
D = 0.4046, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Not only is the p-value ridiculously small, the D statistic is also peculiar. When plotting the two empirical cumulative distribution functions, the difference is much smaller. Not wanting to believe such result I computed the D statistic myself:

```
max(abs(ecdf(slope_background)(0:55) - ecdf(slope_sites)(0:55)))
```

The 55 is set as limit as 55 degrees is the maximum recorded value
Anyway, the resulting D value was 0.1650732, which seems more realistic and is in accordance to the plotted ECDFs.

Any thoughts on that? I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally wrong though.
Also, is there any other, perhaps better way to test this kind of hypothesis? I tried `ad.test` with the same parameters and I suspect that p-value of 4.38e-06 is also not exactly what would be expected.

The histogram of the site distribution:
[image: Hist site]

Cumulative distribution functions of the sites (red) and background data (black dashed line):
[image: ECDF]

Comment: The plots would certainly be helpful, maybe you could include them into your question? The `ks.test` surely calculates the D-statistic correctly. I suspect there is a problem with the input data, if anything. Could you provide the data or parts of it in the question?

Comment: Most settled sites are on gentle slopes but many slopes aren't gentle. Evidently your slopes go up to 55 degrees (which is either a mistake or a cliff). Is this really a credible hypothesis, even as null?

Comment: I added links to the histogram and ECDF graphs (could not add images yet).
There is a point in that the null hypothesis involving 55-degree slope is perhaps not the sanest idea. However without testing for such a hypothesis, how can I really claim that their location is mostly on gentle slopes and that this location is a conscious choice not just a result of the general landscape topography? Those very high slope values of the background data are, however, outliers and do not (or at least should not) affect the big picture.

Comment: Okay, here's something to try: the grid `(0:50)` seems to be very coarse. What is the result if you try this: `max(abs(ecdf(slope_background)(seq(0,55,0.001)) - ecdf(slope_sites)(seq(0,55,0.001))))`

Comment: The result was the same as before: 0.1650732.
By the way, a .csv of the dataset is here: http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~ah25g12/random/Slope.csv
The values for the background data are raster cell counts. For the ks.test I transformed those values using rep() function, e.g.:
`slope_sites <- rep(1:(length(slope_sites)),slope_sites)`

Comment: Thanks. I get the same D from `ks.test` and your custom code whenever I put in the same variables. Given the file that you linked, what is your code for the `ks.test`?

Comment: My code is as follows:  
`slopedata <- read.csv("C:/R/analyses/slope/Slope.csv")  
slope_background <- slopedata$Background  
slope_sites <- slopedata$Sites  
slope_degrees <- slopedata$Value  
slope_background <- rep(1:length(slope_background)),slope_background)  
ecdf_back <- ecdf(slope_background)
slope_sites <- rep(1:(length(slope_sites)),slope_sites)  
ks.test(slope_sites, ecdf_back)`  

Which results in

`One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test  

data:  slope_sites  
D = 0.4046, p-value < 2.2e-16  
alternative hypothesis: two-sided`

Comment: Thanks very much. I spottet the error: Your input for `ks.test` is `ecdf_back`. You should put in the data directly. Try this: `ks.test(slope_sites, slope_background)`. I get the following result: `D = 0.1651, p-value = 0.001144`. This seems to be in line with the D that you've calculated manually.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I get the same D with that. But this is two-sample KS test now. Aren't the p-values calculated differently for 1 and 2 sample tests? If I remember correctly, for 2 sample test, both sample sizes are taken into account and in this case one sample - actually a population itself - is really huge. Wouldn't this distort the p-value calculation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9363/discussion-between-coolserdash-and-ahaav)

Comment: Just thought I'd mention - since you say your data are binned, the K-S p-values don't apply.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, that's good to know! What could be used instead?

Comment: @COOLSerdash You can always calculate or simulate to obtain p-values based on the pattern of ties; essentially a permutation test (or randomization test).

Comment: @Glen_b That's interesting as I've seen many works (true, not by statisticians) using binned data for KS test. However I take note on that and try to do it without binning (going to need lots of RAM I guess) or try permutation approach. Thanks!

Comment: @AHaav The effect of binning is to make the test more conservative (lower power curve, including at the null - i.e. lower type I error rate, higher type II). The smaller the bins, the smaller the effect. You can always simulate to see how big the effect is in situations similar to yours.

Comment: Ah, that's really good to know. I'm using KS quite often for various analyses and the effect of binning has not really come to my mind.

Comment: I just made the same mistake (of putting in the ecdf instead of raw observation into ks.test). I reckon there will be others who will make the same mistake. perhaps @COOLSerdash should answer it formally so other don't have to read through the comments?